# inferSchema in spark-csv package

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

When CSV is read as dataframe in spark, all the columns are read as string. Is there any way to get the actual type of column?

I have the following csv file

```
Name,Department,years_of_experience,DOB
Sam,Software,5,1990-10-10
Alex,Data Analytics,3,1992-10-10
```

I've read the CSV using the below code

```
val df = sqlContext.
                  read.
                  format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
                  option("header", "true").
                  option("inferSchema", "true").
                  load(sampleAdDataS3Location)
df.schema
```

All the columns are read as string. I expect the column *years_of_experience* to be read as *int* and *DOB* to be read as *date*

Please note that I've set the option *inferSchema* to *true*.

I am using the latest version (1.0.3) of spark-csv package

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**2015-07-30**

The latest version is actually [1.1.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv_2.11/1.1.0), but it doesn't really matter since it looks like `inferSchema` [is not included in the latest release](https://web.archive.org/web/20181224145812/https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/110).

**2015-08-17**

The latest version of the package is now [1.2.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv_2.10/1.2.0) (published on 2015-08-06) and schema inference works as expected:

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Department: string (nullable = true)
 |-- years_of_experience: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DOB: string (nullable = true)
```

Regarding automatic date parsing I doubt it will ever happen, or at least not without providing additional metadata.

Even if all fields follow some date-like format it is impossible to say if a given field should be interpreted as a date. So it is either lack of out automatic date inference or spreadsheet like mess. Not to mention issues with timezones for example.

Finally you can easily parse date string manually:

```
sqlContext
  .sql("SELECT *, DATE(dob) as dob_d  FROM df")
  .drop("DOB")
  .printSchema

root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Department: string (nullable = true)
 |-- years_of_experience: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dob_d: date (nullable = true)
```

so it is really not a serious issue.

**2017-12-20**:

Built-in csv parser available since Spark 2.0 supports schema inference for dates and timestamp - it uses two options:

- `timestampFormat` with default `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`
- `dateFormat` with default `yyyy-MM-dd`

See also [How to force inferSchema for CSV to consider integers as dates (with "dateFormat" option)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46529404)

Comment: good explanation, but is it possible to make any field nullable=false?