# Why does reading csv file with empty values lead to IndexOutOfBoundException?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file with the foll struct

```
Name | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Val4 | Val5
John     1      2
Joe      1      2
David    1      2            10    11
```

I am able to load this into an RDD fine. I tried to create a schema and then a `Dataframe` from it and get an `indexOutOfBound` error.

Code is something like this ...

```
val rowRDD = fileRDD.map(p => Row(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(6) )
```

When I tried to perform an action on `rowRDD`, gives the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also shows the error which you get to understand more.

Comment: And paste the sample CSV, maybe the error is in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not answer to your question. But it may help to solve your problem.

From the question I see that you are trying to create a dataframe from a CSV.

Creating dataframe using CSV can be easily done using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) package

With the spark-csv below scala code can be used to read a CSV 
`val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(csvFilePath)`

For your sample data I got the following result

```
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Name|Val1|Val2|Val3|Val4|Val5|
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
| John|   1|   2|    |    |    |
|  Joe|   1|   2|    |    |    |
|David|   1|   2|    |  10|  11|
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

You can also inferSchema with latest version. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31726007/4057655)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this method. Seems to be much better than what i am trying.

Comment: Not been able to get it working.  downloaded and built the package but i cannot get this to work

spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0-s_2.11

where is the jar file expected to be? it is as of now in the path in the spark/bin folder but spark-shell cannot find the package. 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was using [databricks] (http://databricks.com/) to do that. But it should be possible via spark-shell as well. Let me check and update you

Comment: It seems there is an issue with spark-csv README. This command works ```bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0```. And with this I am able to load your CSV using ```val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/sam/tmp/test.csv")```

Comment: Here is the content of the CSV that I am using ```Name,Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4,Val5
John,1,2,,,
Joe,1,2,,,
David,1,2,,10,11```

Comment: What was the location of the jar file ? Did you just put it in the "path" ?

Comment: This worked. Thank you for all your help Samuel! appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

Empty values are not the issue if the CSV file contains fixed number of columns and your CVS looks like this (note the empty field separated with it's own commas):

```
David,1,2,10,,11
```

The problem is your CSV file contains 6 columns, yet with:

```
val rowRDD = fileRDD.map(p => Row(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(6) )
```

You try to read 7 columns. Just change your mapping to:

```
val rowRDD = fileRDD.map(p => Row(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5))
```

And Spark will take care of the rest.

Comment: Hello, 

The p(6) was probably a typo when i keyed in the issue here. In my real program, the number of columns does match. Still have the issue. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution to that problem is replacing missing value with Double.NaN. Suppose I have a file example.csv with columns in it

`David,1,2,10,,11`

You can read the csv file as text file as follow

```
fileRDD=sc.textFile(example.csv).map(x=> {val y=x.split(","); val z=y.map(k=> if(k==""){Double.NaN}else{k.toDouble()})})
```

And then you can use your code to create dataframe from it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.

```
val df = sqlContext
         .read
         .textfile(csvFilePath)
         .map(_.split(delimiter_of_file, -1)
         .map(
             p => 
              Row(
                p(0), 
                p(1),
                p(2),
                p(3),
                p(4),
                p(5),
                p(6))
```

Split using delimiter of your file. When you set `-1` as limit it consider all the empty fields.