# How to force inferSchema for CSV to consider integers as dates (with "dateFormat" option)?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I use Spark 2.2.0

I am reading a csv file as follows:

```scala
val dataFrame = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true")
                          .option("header", true)
                          .option("dateFormat", "yyyyMMdd")
                          .csv(pathToCSVFile)
```

There is one date column in this file, and all records has a value equal to `20171001` for this particular column.

The issue is that spark is inferring that that the type of this column is `integer` rather than `date`. When I remove the `"inferSchema"` option, the type of that column is `string`.

There is no `null` values, nor any wrongly formatted line in this file.

What is the reason/solution for this issue?

Comment: You can try disabling ("inferSchema", "true") and providing custom schema to read the csv file

Comment: I can, but I guess that the "dateFormat" option is made to avoid doing what you suggested, right?

Comment: It needs to be escaped with double quotes if my memory is still good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*If* my understanding is correct, the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVInferSchema.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L86-L98) implies the following order of type inference (with the first types being checked against first):

- `NullType`
- `IntegerType`
- `LongType`
- `DecimalType`
- `DoubleType`
- `TimestampType`
- `BooleanType`
- `StringType`

With that, I think the issue is that `20171001` matches `IntegerType` before even considering `TimestampType` (which uses `timestampFormat` not `dateFormat` option).

One solution would be to define the schema and use it with `schema` operator (of `DataFrameReader`) or let Spark SQL infer the schema and use `cast` operator.

I'd choose the former if the number of fields is not high.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you simply cannot depend on the schema inference due to format ambiguity.

Since input can be parsed both as `IntegerType` (or any higher precision numeric format) as well as `TimestamType` and the former one has higher precedence (internally Spark tries `IntegerType` -> `LongType` -> `DecimaType` -> `DoubleType` -> `TimestampType`) inference mechanism will never reach `TimestampType` case.

To be specific, with schema inference enabled, Spark [will call `tryParseInteger`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7e5359be5ca038fdb579712b18e7f226d705c276/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVInferSchema.scala#L86), which will correctly parse the input and [stop](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7e5359be5ca038fdb579712b18e7f226d705c276/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVInferSchema.scala#L107-L108). Subsequent call will match [the second case](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/405c0e99e7697bfa88aa4abc9a55ce5e043e48b1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVInferSchema.scala#L87) and finish at the same `tryParseInteger` call.

Comment: _"inference mechanism will never reach  TimestampType case."_ I don't think that holds given https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVInferSchema.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L86-L98

Comment: It holds. Order of clauses in pattern match you've linked is not relevant.