# How to make Scala script infer custom column types in a csv/json schema?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, database-schema

I am trying to infer schema when I load a `csv` file in my `SQLContext` using `SparkSession`. Please note that I do not want to use `class` here as I am trying to infer the data file schema as soon it is loaded as I do not have any info about the data types or column names of the file before loading it.

Here is what I am trying out in Scala:

```
package example
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
//import sqlContext.implicits._


object SimpleScalaSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]")
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "local")
      .getOrCreate()
    //val etl1Rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("etl1.json").map(x => x._2)
    val jsonTbl = spark.sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv")
      .option("header", true)
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .option("dateFormat","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
      .csv("s1.csv")

    // print the inferred schema
    jsonTbl.printSchema
  }
}
```

I am able to get `DateTime`, `Integer`, `Double`, `String` as data types for my file. But I want to implement custom data types based on my own `regex` patterns such as fields like SSN, VIN-ID, PhoneNumber etc. which all have a fixed pattern which can be detected using `regex`. This would make schema extraction process for me more accurate and precise. For example, suppose I have a column which contains data formed of 5 or more alphabets and 2 or more numbers, I can say that this column is of type **ID**.

Any ideas on if it is possible to do this using Scala/Spark? Please let me know the implementation part as well if possible or a source to technical documentation.

Comment: _I can say that this column is of type ID_ - it is not clear what you mean. UDTs has been made private long time ago, and there is no id type in Spark. Also, inference mechanism is internal and not plugable. If you are up to modifying Spark source, it is not hard to find.

Comment: I mean that I want to define a certain column type as per my way. Like say if I have a certain types of columns whose values contains 10 numbers with characters such as (, /, - in between, then it can be a contact number. Likewise, I need to define my own custom types. If it is possible to do so by modifying source code, can you point to such source code? I would happily work on that.

Comment: You can start with these two questions - [How to define schema for custom type in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32440461/8371915) and [How to force inferSchema for CSV to consider integers as dates (with “dateFormat” option)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46529404/8371915)